# Looping through an Array and Writing Error Message(s)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have a table `A:G` and within are specific required columns (`A`,`C`,`D`,`F`,`G`) where I am highlighting the cell and in `G` writing a message. Column `F` is a date and I am also checking that it is < today. Lastly, I am having trouble with a 1004 error so I can't get into the For statements.

My ultimate goal would be to write multiple error messages in column `G`, but i am not there yet.

[image: Mocked up ultimate results]

Any help is greatly appreciated?

```
Option Base 1

Sub ValidateArrayColumns()

Dim errormsg() As Variant
Dim Drng As Long
Dim Row As Single
Dim Column As Single
Dim tmpDate As Variant
Dim IsError As Boolean
Dim arrReq(5) As Variant
Dim i As Single

arrReq(1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, 1)
arrReq(2) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, 3)
arrReq(3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, 4)
arrReq(4) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, 6)
arrReq(5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Row, 7)

    Drng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    i = 1

    For Row = 2 To Drng
        For Column = 1 To 7
            If Column = arrReq(i) Then
                For i = 1 To arrReq(5)
                    If Cells(Row, arrReq(i)) = "" Then       'Required fields
                        Cells(Row, arrReq(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        IsError = True
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next Column

            'Checks Date
            tmpDate = Cells(Row, 4).Value
            If tmpDate = "" Then
                Cells(Row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                IsError = True
            ElseIf tmpDate < Date Then
                Cells(Row, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                IsError = True
            End If

            'Writes error message
            If IsError = True Then
                Cells(Row, 8).Value = "Highlighted fields contain errors"
            End If

            IsError = False
    Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59699936/edit) and post a sample image of your data.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a mocked up image of my ultimate results. GridLock helped out quite a bit but the code skips over the If statement. Again I appreciate all your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Option Explicit

Option Base 1

Private Sub ValidateRange()

    Dim evalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim evalRow As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range

    Dim evalSheetName As String
    Dim evalColumns As String

    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRowColumn As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim relativeCol As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim columnCommments As Long

    Dim errorType As Long

    Dim errorCounter As Long
    Dim errorDescrip As String
    Dim errorConcat As String

    Dim validationRule(5) As Variant

    ' Adjust the parameters to fit your needs
    evalSheetName = "Sheet2"
    evalColumns = "A:G"
    lastRowColumn = "A"                          ' Column where it's going to be searched for the last non empty row
    firstRow = 2                                 ' Skip headers

    columnCommments = 8


    ' Define the rules like column number, validation type, error description

    validationRule(1) = Array(1, "Non empty")
    validationRule(2) = Array(3, "Non empty")
    validationRule(3) = Array(4, "Non empty")
    validationRule(4) = Array(6, "Non empty")
    validationRule(5) = Array(7, "Greater than today")

    ' Set a reference to the sheet where the validation takes place
    Set evalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(evalSheetName)

    ' Find the last row with a value in a specific column
    lastRow = evalSheet.Cells(evalSheet.Rows.Count, lastRowColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Define the range to be validated
    Set evalRange = Intersect(evalSheet.Range(evalColumns), evalSheet.Rows(firstRow & ":" & lastRow))

    ' Search per row
    For Each evalRow In evalRange.Rows

        ' Reset error counter
        errorCounter = 0

        ' Reset error comments
        evalSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, columnCommments).Value = vbNullString

        ' Loop through all cells and check if they are required and empty
        For Each evalCell In evalRow.Cells

            ' Reset error description
            errorDescrip = vbNullString


            ' Cell column is relative to the column where the range begins
            relativeCol = (evalCell.Column - evalRange.Column + 1)

            ' Get the validation result per cell
            errorType = IsCellValidAndReturnErrorType(evalCell, relativeCol, validationRule)

            Select Case errorType
            Case 0
                ' Reset format
                evalCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Case 1
                errorDescrip = errorDescrip & " " & "Cell cannot be empty"
                evalCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Case 2
                errorDescrip = errorDescrip & " " & "Cell should be a date"
                evalCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case 3
                errorDescrip = errorDescrip & " " & "Cell should be greater than today"
                    evalCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case Else

            End Select


            If errorType <> 0 Then

                If errorCounter >= 1 Then
                    errorConcat = " | "
                Else
                    errorConcat = vbNullString
                End If

                evalSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, columnCommments).Value = evalSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, columnCommments).Value & errorConcat & evalCell.Address & " has error: " & errorDescrip
                errorCounter = errorCounter + 1
            End If

        Next evalCell

    Next evalRow

End Sub

Private Function IsCellValidAndReturnErrorType(ByVal evalCell As Range, ByVal cellColumn As Long, ByVal validationRule As Variant) As Long

    Dim errorType As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim errorDescrip As String

    For counter = 1 To UBound(validationRule, 1)

        ' Check if cell column has validations
        If cellColumn = validationRule(counter)(1) Then

            ' Check if meets validation rule
            Select Case validationRule(counter)(2)
            Case "Non empty"
                If evalCell.Value = vbNullString Then
                    errorType = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case "Greater than today"
                If IsDate(evalCell.Value) = False Then
                    errorType = 2
                    Exit For
                ElseIf evalCell.Value < Date Then
                    errorType = 3
                    Exit For
                End If
            Case Else
                errorType = 0
            End Select
        End If

    Next counter

    IsCellValidAndReturnErrorType = errorType

End Function
```

Some suggestions:

1. Always use Option explicit at the top of your modules / classes (you'll avoid making mistakes using undeclared variables)
2. Try to name your variables to something meaningful and readable

Comment: Wow! This is going to take me a bit to digest, but definitely something to learn from. I thought about using the Select Case. Thank you very much. However, I am not seeing that it is writing the error messages. Is there a way to capture multiple errors in a row?

Comment: Thank you very much. I really like the cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the row variable, the default row = 0 so

`Worksheets ("Sheet2"). Cells (Row, 1)` will be equivalent to `Worksheets ("Sheet2"). Cells (0, 1)` this causes an error -> you need to assign a suitable value

Here are some small changes in the your code:

```
 Option Base 1

Sub ValidateArrayColumns()

Dim errormsg() As Variant
Dim Drng As Long
Dim Row As Single
Dim Column As Single
Dim tmpDate As Variant
Dim IsError As Boolean
Dim arrReq(5) As Variant
Dim i As Single
Row = 1 '///
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    arrReq(1) = .Cells(Row, 1)
    arrReq(2) = .Cells(Row, 3)
    arrReq(3) = .Cells(Row, 4)
    arrReq(4) = .Cells(Row, 6)
    arrReq(5) = .Cells(Row, 7)

    Drng = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
    i = 1

    For Row = 2 To Drng
        For Column = 1 To 7
            If Column = arrReq(i) Then
                For i = 1 To arrReq(5)
                    If Cells(Row, arrReq(i)) = vbNullString Then 'Required fields
                        Cells(Row, arrReq(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        IsError = True
                        Exit For '///
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next Column

            'Checks Date
            tmpDate = Cells(Row, 7).Value
            If tmpDate = vbNullString Then
                Cells(Row, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                IsError = True
            ElseIf tmpDate < Date Then
                Cells(Row, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                IsError = True
            End If

        'Writes error message
        If IsError = True Then
            Cells(Row, 8).Value = "Highlighted fields contain errors"
        End If

        IsError = False

    Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me step through the code. However, it skips the Required section because of my If statement...   If Column = arrReq(i)   ... I have edited my post with an image of the results I want.